# Can't get two Geopandas to line up in a plot

Tags: python-3.x, geopandas

[My Code](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VLAtv.png)
I'm trying to get these two Geopandas to overlap in a graph and have tried numerous things with the projection system to no avail. The output is always the two geodataframes far apart like this.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y6wCo.png)

I've tried changing the crs and multiple different crs related commands as well as spatial joins.

Found the problem had nothing to do with code and was due to the shape folder I had loaded in.

Comment: Please avoid pictures of code when you can simply copy/paste it here in code brackets. Concerning your problem, I don't think you are supposed to set CRS that way, try using the `set_crs()`method instead: https://geopandas.org/en/stable/docs/reference/api/geopandas.GeoDataFrame.set_crs.html

Comment: I tried that, a while back and it did not work, I found that the problem wasn't code related and had more to do with the shapefile I loaded in for Boston City.

Comment: post the code and not the pictures of code.
Users need to be able to replicate the problem quickly, 
which text allows for (and pictures do not).
[how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)